What's the rate of return on a mortgage?
I'm trying to understand mortgages from first principles, from the perspective of a borrower.
Let $S_t$ be the price of the asset bought with the loan at time $t$ (i.e. house). Let $\alpha$ be the downpayment ratio, $r$ the interest rate, $T$ the maturity of the mortgage and $c$ the continuously paid (for simplicity) coupon rate.
The borrower's value at time $0 \le t \le T$ is given by
\begin{align}
V_t &= S_t - S_0 c \int_t^T e^{-r(u-t)} \mathrm{d} u \\
&= S_t - S_0 \frac{c}{r} \left[ 1 - e^{-r(T-t)} \right]
\end{align}
The par coupon with downpayment $\alpha S_0$ is given by
$$ c = r \frac{ 1 - \alpha}{1 - e^{-rT}} $$
so that $V_0 = \alpha S_0$.
I can't seem to answer simple questions like

Of the 3 parameters $\alpha$, $r$, $T$ can one be eliminated wlog?
Is there a closed form or approximate way to get the leverage $\frac{\mathrm{d}V_t/V_t}{\mathrm{d}S_t/S_t}$, even for a simple model like $\mathrm{d}S_t/S_t = \text{const}$?

I would like to eventually get to understanding the breakeven between mortgage rates and real estate returns.
Would appreciate any pointers!

If $T = \infty$, $V_t$ simplifies to
$$V_t = S_t - S_0 (1 - \alpha) $$
and we have
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} V_t}{V_t} = \frac{\mathrm{d} S_t}{S_t} \frac{1}{1 - \frac{S_0}{S_t}(1-\alpha)}.$$
Letting $S_t = S_0 e^{\mu t}$, the leverage is
$$ \frac{1}{1 - \frac{S_0}{S_t}(1-\alpha)}  = \frac{1}{1 - e^{-\mu t }(1-\alpha)}.$$
which starts at $1/(1-\alpha)$ and tends to 1 if $\mu > 0$, stays at its initial value if $\mu = 0$, gets weird if $\mu < 0$.
